# How to make my image gallery width responsive to div below it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have an image gallery with name **slider1_container** and it's style properties are specified within the HTML code such as:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:700px;
    height: 600px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">
```

This works perfectly, except that the slider is wider than the div box beneath this. This div box is 100% of the width of the parent class "rightcolumn", and my **slider1_container** div is ALSO within this class, but since it's width of 700px is set within the HTML code, it doesn't seem to be responsive at other viewport sizes.

I've tried to use media queries at various points to change the width of the **slider1_container** to something smaller than 700px, but it seems that the width specified in the HTML code overrules that.

[DEAD LINK REMOVED, PLEASE UPDATE]

If I set the 700px to auto, the width works perfectly BUT the image gallery shows only black when you load the page, until you choose another photo it will quickly appear (javascript issue it sounds).

If you resize the viewport on my site you can see the image gallery's width doesn't match the div box below it How can I make this responsive like the other div?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for whatever slideshow plugin it is that you are using. It most likely has settings for responsiveness. If not, you can find a million different responsive slideshow plugins [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=responsive+slideshow+plugin)